How to install libc debug symbols (libc6-dbg) on Ubuntu 20.04? /usr/lib/debug empty after installing libc6-dbg
I need the debug symbols for libc on Ubuntu 20.04 for performance profiling in gperftools (or perf). I checked how to install them and used:
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
After successfull Installation I don't find any libc related files in /usr/lib/debug. What could be the issue?
purge and repeated install did not help.
The version of libc shown matches my system version 2.31-0ubuntu9.15.
I found this thread which seems related How to Install Debug Symbols for libc on Ubuntu 22.04?. The only answer points to this forum entry https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1918035.
When I search for the debug info that way I get an entry in a hidden folder. However I'm not sure what to do with it:
$ dpkg -L libc6-dbg | grep $(readelf -n /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so | grep 'Build ID' | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c 3-)
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/c9/a47e328eb2f1f41bcbcf31f9c11b9e17aa2a83.debug


Are you sure ? I get a error (can not found package) when I run sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg  on Ubuntu 20.04.

"Unsure what to do with it" - usually, you need not do anything.  Your debugger should find it just fine where it is.

@life888888 Yes, I get "libc6-dbg is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.15)." when retrying.

@TobySpeight I get no symbolization of libc calls in gperftools, even when copying this file to /usr/lib/debug/libc-2.31.so and adding PPROF_BINARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug before running pprof.

So the question isn't about installing (which would be off-topic, since apt-get isn't a programming tool), but how to get gperftools to use the symbols?  I think you should edit the question (especially the title) to make that clear and attract someone who may be able to help.

BTW, dpkg -L libc6-dbg ought to show which files the package owns - easier than searching.

@TobySpeight I wasn't quite sure if these are the correct debug symbols, or if they're installed in the right place, hence the title. How can I make sure that it's not an installation issue?

@TonySpeight The output of dpkg -L libc6-dbg is being filtered by the build ID. I got this from that other forum entry. It owns a lot of such .debug files with different build IDs and a doc folder.

And you're sure that it's the debug symbols for ld-2.31.so that you want, and not the ones for libc.so.6?

Ah, that was an oversight, didn't see that when copy-pasting from the forum entry.

Couple things. First, gperftools ships really old and deprecated pprof implementation (see e.g. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1049383). You should (manually for now) get go implementation from github.com/google/pprof. Second, PPROF_BINARY_PATH is path to pprof program. And it invokes addr2line and similar tools. It is up to them to handle debug info.

Also please note that libc.so and other .so regardless of debug info still have "dynamic symbols" (i.e. those listed by objdump -T as opposed to objdump -t). For libc those are usually more than good enough. I.e. as long as addr2line and similar tools exist on your system and are functional. pprof shouldn't need those -dbg packages. At least for libc
